# GDI+ DrawImage function

Tags: gdi+, zooming

There is something I am missing. Say I have the following code:

```
private Bitmap source = new Bitmap (some_stream);
Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(100,100);
Rectangle newRect = new Rectangle(0, 0, bmp.Width, bmp.Height);
Rectangle toZoom= new Rectangle(0, 0, 10, 10);

Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp);
g.DrawImage(source, newRect, toZoom, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
```

My goal is to zoom-in the 10x10 pixels on the top left corner of the source picture. After I created the graphics object g and called DrawImage: the requested rectangle (toZoom) will be copied to bmp, or will it be displayed on the screen? I am a bit confused, can somebody please clarify?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You code will only give you an in-memory bitmap (which won't automatically be displayed to the screen).  A simple way to display this would be to put a 100 x 100 `PictureBox` on your form, and set its `Image` property like this (using the `Bitmap` from your code above):

```
pictureBox1.Image = bmp;
```

Also, you'll want some `using` blocks in your code:

```
using (private Bitmap source = new Bitmap (some_stream))
{
    Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(100,100);
    Rectangle newRect = new Rectangle(0, 0, bmp.Width, bmp.Height);
    Rectangle toZoom= new Rectangle(0, 0, 10, 10);
    using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp))
    {
        g.DrawImage(source, newRect, toZoom, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
    }
    pictureBox1.Image = bmp;
}
```

Note that there is no `using` block with `bmp` - this is because you're setting it as the PictureBox's Image property.  The `using` block automatically calls an object's Dispose method at the end of the block's scope, which you don't want to do since it will still be in use.

Answer (score 0):

it will be copied and not displayed.